# Filter data by day range in Elasticsearch using Python DSL

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I wrote this below method to filter data for last 8 days

```py
def method_one(query) -> Query:
    gte = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=query)).date()
    lt = (datetime.datetime.now()).date()
    print(gte, lt)
    return Q(MultiMatch(
        query=filter("range", {"lastModifiedDate": {"gte": gte, "lt": lt}}
                        ),
        fields=['lastModifiedDate']
    ))
```

I want to filter data based on the `lastModifiedDate` field by forming an Elasticsearch `Query` object in Python.
For example if I give **/lastModifiedDate=8** (Rest API Call), it should return data by filtering for the last 8 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `datetime` module to construct date queries in Elasticsearch -- you can use [built-in date math](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates):

```py
from json import dumps
from elasticsearch_dsl.search import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import Q, MultiMatch


def date_range_query(num_of_days):
    if not isinstance(num_of_days, int):
        raise Exception(
            'expected numeric & positive `num_of_days`, got `%s`' % str(num_of_days))

    return Q(
        "range",
        lastModifiedDate={
            "gte": "now-%dd" % num_of_days,
            "lt": "now"
        }
    )


try:
    q = date_range_query(8)
    print(dumps(q.to_dict(), indent=2))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

which'd print

```json
{
  "range": {
    "lastModifiedDate": {
      "gte": "now-8d",
      "lt": "now"
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternatively**, if you insisted on using `datetime.date` objects, you'd need to stringify the dates first. Now, when you do that with `str(...)`, you're in fact calling [`.__str()__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.__str__) which then calls [`.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) and returns a string formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Now, your `lastModifiedDate` field's mapping may have a different format. As such, it's good practice to declare the format of your `range` query:

```py
gte = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=num_of_days)).date()
lt = (datetime.datetime.now()).date()

return Q(
    "range",
    lastModifiedDate={
        "gte": str(gte),
        "lt": str(lt),
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"  # keep in mind that the format in ES conforms to Java syntax, not python
    }
)
```

which'd produce a similar query but with concrete, spelled-out dates:

```json
{
  "range": {
    "lastModifiedDate": {
      "gte": "2021-02-26",
      "lt": "2021-03-06",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joe. You saved lot of my time. Trying to fix this for the past 2 days. Thanks again.